# How do I move the date and time to the far right of the bottom panel in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, panel

I've looked for Gnome extensions to no avail. I'm using Dash to Dock to make icons maximize and minimize whenever I click them (like in Windows), but this extension doesn't support moving the clock. The other extensions I tried don't work with this version of Ubuntu.

All I want to move is the clock, currently located at the centre of the top panel.

Is there any way for me to do this? I tried Dash to Panel as well but whenever I enable it the top panel and all its information simply disappears. It doesn't show up in the bottom panel like it should.

uname -r shows 4.15.0-20-generic

Thanks.

Comment: "*The other extensions I tried don't work with this version of Ubuntu*" is not really helpful. Which ones have you tried exactly? Also many extensions which don't *officially* support newer GNOME shell version, work fine nonetheless. Have you tried this: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2/move-clock/

Comment: I've tried Frippery Move Clock (which doesn't move the clock to the bottom panel), Dash to Panel, and Dash to Dock. None of these extensions move the clock to the bottom. Dash to Dock claims to, but when I select the option to move the top panel to the bottom, the top panel simply disappears and nothing shows up at the bottom panel. I even mentioned the last two in my original post...

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Do you have two panels? Could you post a screenshot? Are you in GNOME Classic or Flashback session? Dash to Dock is not supposed to tweak top or bottom panel anyway.

Comment: @New2Coding Did you ever find a solution for this?